# IllegalArgumentException on RMI Call

Tags: java, rmi, illegalargumentexception

I have the following class definitions:

```
public class Client extends AbstractServer implements IClient

public abstract class AbstractServer implements IServer
```

The goal is to create a distributed/peer to peer game (for a school assignment) using Java RMI. P2P in a sense that at the start, there is 1 client that acts as the "server" accepting client's requests to join game etc. This primary server also selects a backup server, that functions as the primary (then selecting a new backup) if the old primary fails.

In this sense, all clients can act as a server. Thats why I modeled the `Client` this way (extending an `AbstractServer` which implements the server code)

The problem is: In client's main method:

```
client = new Client();
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
IServer stub = (IServer) registry.lookup("Maze");

client.id = stub.joinGame(client); // this line triggers exception
```

Exception details:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:275)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:252)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.joinGame(Unknown Source)
    at client.Client.main(Client.java:31)
```

Whats wrong? The IServer implementation looks like:

```
public interface IServer extends Remote {
    public int joinGame(Client client) throws RemoteException;
    ...
}
```

Why the problem? `joinGame` accepts a `Client` which I provided?

By the way: the source is on **[GitHub](https://github.com/jiewmeng/cs5223-assignment1)**

Comment: Not sure about this. But did you try using `IClient` as the formal parameter type in `joinGame`? Like: public `int joinGame(IClient client)`. That is how I've usually coded stuff on RMI.

Answer (score 1):

You've changed your remote interface between compiling and deploying to either server or client; or you have classes by the same name in different packages.